# Pareto distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

So I'm given a Pareto distribution with parameters $\alpha >0$ and $k>0$ which is the form of
\begin{equation*}
f(x) = \frac{\alpha k^\alpha}{x^{\alpha+1}},~x > k. 
\end{equation*}
I found the maximum likelihood estimator of $k$,

$\widehat{k}=$min$(x_{1}, x_{2},..., x_{n})$ and it's distribution which was, 
$f_{\widehat{k}}(x) = \frac{ank^{\alpha n}}{x^{\alpha n + 1}}$

1) How would I go about finding the distribution of $\frac{k}{\widehat{k}}$

2) Find a 95% confidence interval using that? I know I need a function of $k$ and the estimator $\widehat{k}$ and that's why I am asking for it in 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you calculate the cumulative distribution function of $\frac{k}{\hat{k}}$.

Comment: Yup then differentiate it to find the pdf right? But how would I set it up since $\frac{k}{\widehat{k}} = \frac{k}{min(x_{1}, ..., x_{n})}$

Comment: For $x\geq k>0$, $P\left(\frac{k}{\hat{k}}\leq x\right) = P\left( \hat{k}\geq \frac{k}{x}\right) = P\left(\min (x_1,\dots,x_n)\geq \frac{k}{x}\right) = \dots $

Comment: Got it cheers August!

Comment: Just wondering what type of distribution for am I suppose to obtain, I get an unrecognisable distribution?

Comment: What's your result ?

Comment: I got $f_{\frac{k}{\widehat{k}}}(x) = (an)x^{an-1}$ Isn't this a Pareto with $\alpha n$ and $1$ Is this what you also got?

Comment: Yes but be careful, this expression is not true for all values of $x$. I don't know if this distribution has a name, but it shouldn't prevent you from finding a confidence interval.